# Get the list of registered view for navigation with Prism

Tags: wpf, prism, dryioc

I am working on a modular application with Prism DryIoc on WPF

In my modules I have views registered for navigation like this

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
     containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Manual1View>();
     containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Manual2View>();
     containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ProductionView>();       
}
```

Is there a way to find the list of currently registered views for navigation directly from Prism or the Container ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want those views to automatically show up in a region, register them for that region (instead of registering for navigation and navigating by hand).

Comment: I want to be able to list them in some configurable HMI, for exemple I have some items controls with buttons that will perform RequestNavigate to a view and I want the user to be able to choose a registered view.

Comment: Better not abuse the container, then, and roll out your own registry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should roll out your own registry for those views you want the user to be able to select from. That one could also do the registration for navigation, so you don't have to duplicate the registration code.

```
internal class MachineModeRegistry : IMachineModeRegistry
{
    public MachineModeRegistry(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        _containerRegistry = containerRegistry;
    }

    #region IMachineModeRegistry
    public void RegisterView<T>()
    {
        _containerRegistry.RegisterViewForNavigation<T>(nameof(T));
        _listOfViews.Add( nameof(T) );
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> RegisteredViews => _listOfViews;
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly List<string> _listOfViews = new List<string>();
    private readonly IContainerRegistry _containerRegistry;
    #endregion
}
```

and in the app or bootstrapper's `RegisterTypes`

```
_containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IMachineModeRegistry>(new MachineModeRegistry(_containerRegistry);
```

and in the modules'

```
 _containerRegistry.Resolve<IMachineRegistry>().RegisterView<Manual1View>();
```

Note: `Resolve` in `RegisterTypes` is evil and error-prone, but can't be avoided here.

Note: you can't inject `IContainerRegistry`, therefore we use `RegisterInstance` (registering the container registry instead would have been very evil)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to find the list of currently registered views for navigation directly from Prism or the Container ?

Not using the `IContainerRegistry` interface but using the DryIoc implementation:

```
if (containerRegistry is DryIocContainerExtension dryIoc)
{
    IContainer container = dryIoc.Instance;
    Type[] types = container.GetServiceRegistrations()?
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.OptionalServiceKey?.ToString()))
        .Select(x => x.ImplementationType)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this get _all_ named registrations (not just the views)?

Comment: I will try this, but I think I will also find all the other registrations (services and so on, but may be it can be filtered)

Comment: `GetServiceRegistrations` gets *all* registrations so you have to filter them, for example using the `OptionalServiceKey` as I showed in the answer. It this filtering isn't good enough, you'll have to keep track of the views yourself one way or another.